# gdb source code breakpoint.c - 0x4e 0x4f

Tags: gdb

I am looking into gdb, for breakpoint implementation. For ease I took the very first GDB release 2.51 (released 1988). I see the break point insert data as -

```
#define BREAKPOINT {0x4e, 0x4f}
```

what is 0x4e and 0x4f ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0x4E 0x4F is the Motorola 68000 machine instruction for "TRAP #15".  The TRAP instruction forces an exception to occur, and on certain platforms trap #15 is defined as a breakpoint exception.  This is why 0x4E and 0x4F appear in your GDB 2.51 source for handling platforms such as sun3.

References:

This [Motorola M68000 Family Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) contains the details of the TRAP instruction on page 4-188.  Specifically, the instruction is represented by the 12-bit value 010011100100 followed by the 4-bit "vector" (in this case, 1111).  So "TRAP #15" is represented by 0x4E 0x4F.  Sun specifically uses vector 15 for breakpoint/tracing -- a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sunos+%22trap+%2315%22&pws=0) reveals numerous comments and source code examples.

Comment: I just added links to some technical resources.